# VSCode behavior

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When running my C++ program in VSCode something odd is happening.

If I run without debugging I get the result in the debug tab, and the terminal tab is displaying `Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.`

And why is the bottom bar red when I'm running my program?

My platform is a MacBook Pro M1

Yes I'm a newbie....

Comment: What plugins do you have install to run the program? CMake, code runner or something else?

Comment: I got C/C++, C/C++ Extension Pack and C/C++ Themes, Make tools from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The red bar at the bottom means you are in debug mode.

Comment: But I'm running without debugging?